# How to get 4 values for different Indexes and names of rasters for set of points?

Tags: arcpy, raster, cursor, numpy

I am trying to  get 4 values for different Indexes and names of rasters  for set of points, but get problem with defining function    def extractIndex(raster, pathName).

```
#List of Folders  4 Folders     for   rasters with  different Indexes:
path1 = r"C:\Users\1_fire_dNBR/"
path2 = r"C:\Users\1_fire_RdNBR/"
path3 = r"C:\Users\2_fire_dNBR/"
path4 = r"C:\Users\2_fire_RdNBR/"

#Points:
inputPoints = r"C:\Users\select3.shp"

# Rasters in specific folder:
RExtents = [arcpy.Describe(R).extent for R in arcpy.ListRasters()]

#Names of rasters:
 RNames = [arcpy.Describe(R).name[:-9] for R in arcpy.ListRasters()]  # extract  names of rasters


def extractIndex(raster, pnt, pathName):
    cr = arcpy.ListRasters(RNames[counter]+'*')  # names of fires
    rast = arcpy.Raster(cr[0])  #Raster Object   (path and raster   here)
    V = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray[rast, pnt, 1, 1]   # specific value of Point from   raster
    return V[0]
#Code:
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputPoints, ["SHAPE@","dNBR_1", "RdNBR_1", "dNBR_2", "RdNBR_2", "name"]) as iCur:
    for pnt in iCur:
       counter = 0
       for iR in RExtents:          
            if iR.contains(pnt[0]):

                # Names of path  with  Raster's Data Sets:
                dNBR_1= extractIndex(RNames[counter], pnt, path1)
                RdNBR_1= extractIndex(RNames[counter], pnt, path2)
                dNBR_2= extractIndex(RNames[counter], pnt, path3)
                RdNBR_2= extractIndex(RNames[counter], pnt, path4)

                iCur.UpdateRow[pnt[0],dNBR_1, RdNBR_1, dNBR_2, RdNBR_2, RNames[counter]]       
              counter =+ 1
```

Running the above code gives an error:

> File "", line 33, in 
>       dNBR_1 = extractIndex(RNames[counter], pnt[0], path1)
>
> File "", line 20, in extractIndex
>       V = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray[rast, pnt, 1, 1]   # specific value of Point from specific  raster
>
> TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: What happens when you run this script? Do you have an error message you can share? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I think you should be able to cut your code down to a smaller code snippet that you can use to illustrate your problem.  I suspect that the process of creating this will probably lead to you solving your own problem.  At the moment I think there is a little too much code accompanied by too little explanation of what each part of the code is intended to do to attract a potential answerer.